# Powershell: Search data in *.txt files to export into *.csv

Tags: powershell

First of all, this is my first question here. I often come here to browse existing topics, but now I'm hung on my own problem. And I didn't found a helpful resource right now. My biggest concern would be, that it won't work in Powershell... At the moment I try to get a small Powershell tool to save me a lot of time. For those who don't know cw-sysinfo, it is a tool that collects information of any host system (e.g. Hardware-ID, Product Key and stuff like that) and generates *.txt files.
My point is, if you have 20, 30 or 80 server in a project, it is a huge amount of time to browse all files and just look for those lines you need and put them together in a *.csv file.

What I have working is more like the basic of the tool, it browses all *.txt in a specific path and checks for my keywords. And here is the problem that I just can use the words prior to those I really need, seen as follow:

```
    Operating System:         Windows XP
    Product Type:             Professional
    Service Pack:             Service Pack 3
    ...
```

I don't know how I can tell Powershell to search for "Product Type:"-line and pick the following "Professional" instead. Later on with keys or serial numbers it will be the same problem, that is why I just can't browse for "Standard" or "Professional".

I placed my keywords($controls) in an extra file that I can attach the project folders and don't need to edit in Powershell each time. Code looks like this:

```
    Function getStringMatch 
    { 
      # Loop through the project directory
      Foreach ($file In $files) 
      { 
        # Check all keywords
        ForEach ($control In $controls) 
        { 
          $result = Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String $control -quiet -casesensitive 
          If ($result -eq $True) 
          { 

            $match = $file.FullName 
            # Write the filename according to the entry
            "Found :  $control  in:  $match" | Out-File $output -Append 
          } 
        } 
      } 
    } 

    getStringMatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the kind of thing you need, I've changed [Select-String](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) to not use the `-quiet` option, this will return a matches object, one of the properties of this is the `line` I then split the line on the ':' and trim any spaces.  These results are then placed into a new [PSObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/05/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable.aspx) which in turn is added to an array.  The array is then put back on the pipeline at the end.

I also moved the call to `get-content` to avoid reading each file more than once.

```
  # Create an array for results
  $results = @()

  # Loop through the project directory
  Foreach ($file In $files) 
  { 
    # load the content once
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName 

    # Check all keywords
    ForEach ($control In $controls) 
    { 
      # find the line containing the control string
      $result = $content | Select-String $control -casesensitive 
      If ($result) 
      { 
        # tidy up the results and add to the array
        $line = $result.Line -split ":"
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FileName = $file.FullName 
            Control = $line[0].Trim()
            Value = $line[1].Trim()
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
  # return the results
  $results
```

Adding the results to a csv is just a case of piping the results to [Export-Csv](http://ss64.com/ps/export-csv.html)

```
$results | Export-Csv -Path "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Great, this is excatly what was in my mind since the last Friday, but in same cases (like mine) it is hard to find the right words to even google it. You can guess how much unrelated sites stopped me from finding this help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want some way to parse each line from your report files and extract values for some "keys". Here are a few lines to give you an idea of how you could proceede. The example is for one file, but can be generalized very easily.

```
$config = Get-Content ".\config.txt"


# The stuff you are searching for

$keys = @(
    "Operating System",
    "Product Type",
    "Service Pack"
)

foreach ($line in $config)
{
    $keys | %{
        $regex = "\s*?$($_)\:\s*(?<value>.*?)\s*$"

        if ($line -match $regex)
        {
            $value = $matches.value
            Write-Host "Key: $_`t`tValue: $value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, it is just awesome, how handy and light weighted solutions come up with Powershell ;) Actually I'm thinking about just making it a perfect match in csv, so each machine has one line with x rows. That would save me from running macros while formating it in Excel.