# Pull data from a document

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that has data as follows:

```
07:30 - 07:45PMTS09526052 | Sev9 | Location| | Due: 12/23/2016
NON PC HARDWARE - TROUBLESHOOT SW
Complete this Job
```

These lines will show up multiple times throughout the document, with variations, such as the alphanumeric characters after the letters "PMT" on line one.

I need to find a way so whenever it finds "PMT" it pulls that and the next 9 symbols, drops it in a CSV, and then puts the "Complete this job" line in the next spot on the CSV.

I know I'll need to set the pattern as `PMT[ST][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` (where `$WLDir` is the filename.):

```
Select-String $WLDir -pattern “PMT[ST][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]”
```

I can't figure out what my next move is to isolate that part and the line 2 lines down and set them as cell data in a CSV.  Can anyone help?  I apologize as it looks like I've not done my homework here, but I've been trying to use [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712397/powershell-search-data-in-txt-files-to-export-into-csv) and some [some Hey! Scripting Guy!](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692806.aspx) as references, but I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the result should looks like but I consider you want a CSV with a `Time`, `Topic` and `Status` column:

```
Select-String $WLDir -pattern '(PMT[ST]\d{8})' -Context 0,2 | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        Topic = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
        Status = $_.Context.PostContext[1]
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will output:

```
"Time","Topic","Status"
"PMTS09526052","NON PC HARDWARE - TROUBLESHOOT SW","Complete this Job"
```

Comment: This is all I would have done. Pretty sure `[S|T]` works fine as `[ST]` as the later is a range

Comment: @Matt Its actual the same I guess, its just the notation I prefer. Range would be [S-T] (which in this case would also be the same ;-))

Comment: Brilliant!  Excellent.  I thought it was going to be... oh, I don't know.  Maybe A MILLION times more complicated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I also like the `-Context` parameter of the `Select-String` cmdlet. Without it, it would be more complicated ;-)

Comment: Nicely done; it is `[ST]` and `(S|T)` that are the same (apart from the latter creating a capture group). By contrast, `[S|T]`, due to adding `|` to the character _set_ inside `[...]`, also matches literal `|`: compare `'|' -match '[S|T]'` to `'|' -match '(S|T)'` / `'|' -match '[ST]'`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks. And you are right, `[S|T]` includes the pipe character. I fixed it.