# Calculate time from document

Tags: powershell

Building on [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191768/pull-data-from-a-document/41191932#41191932) (thanks @MartinBrandl), I'd like to grab the time values to calculate time as well.

Example data:

```
07:30 - 07:45PMTS09526052 | Sev9 | Location| | Due: 12/23/2016
NON PC HARDWARE - TROUBLESHOOT SW
Complete this Job
```

Martin Brandl came up with this to get the other data I need:

```
Select-String $WLDir -pattern '(PMT[S|T]\d{8})' -Context 0,2 | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Time = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    Topic = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
    Status = $_.Context.PostContext[1]
}
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'd like to grab the `07:30 - 07:45` bit from right before the `PMT` part.  I plan to use this to get the time:

```
$StartTime = [However I get the `7:30` here]
$EndTime = [However I get the `7:45` here]
$ElapsedTime = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartTime –End $EndTime).TotalHours
```

and I'd add a fourth field to the CSV:

```
Elapsed = $ElapsedTime
```

But I'm not sure how specifically to grab the two times and isolate them as variables.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: `'(PMT[S|T]\d{8})'` -> `'(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(PMT[S|T]\d{8})'` and adjust the group numbers accordingly.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers as always, thanks.  I'm not sure what we're going for here.  If you're telling me to replace `'(PMT[S|T]\d{8})'` with `'(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(PMT[S|T]\d{8})'` that replaces the first field with just the start time.  I'm looking to take the time to calculate the time passed and put that in a different field in the CSV.  I still need the PMT to be in the "Time" field.  I need the calculate time to be its own entry in the CSV.

Comment: The parentheses in the regular expressions define capturing groups that allow you to reference the captured groups as `$_.Matches.Groups[<index>]`. Index 1 gives you the start time, so you'll get the end time from index ...

Comment: Okay, I honestly don't get the format of ` - ` for between the first two fields, but that works.  Thanks for putting up with me, @AnsgarWiechers.  Care to make an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first question the time span wasn't in  the Csv
as it wasn't referenced by the RegEx. Now it is and `7:30` 
being $matches.groups[1].value and so forth

```
$WLDir = ".\File.txt" 
$Pattern='(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(PMT[S|T]\d{8})'
Select-String $WLDir -pattern $Pattern -Context 0,2 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $StartTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value,"HH:mm",$null)
        $EndTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value,"HH:mm",$null)
        $ElapsedTime = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartTime –End $EndTime).TotalHours
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
            Topic = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
            Status = $_.Context.PostContext[1]
            ElapsedHrs = $ElapsedTime
        }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Giving this output (I added a second testentry with PMTT)

```
"Time","Topic","Status","ElapsedHrs"
"PMTS09526052","NON PC HARDWARE - TROUBLESHOOT SW","Complete this Job","0,25"
"PMTT10952605","NON PC HARDWARE - TROUBLESHOOT SW","Complete this Job","0,25"
```

The column Time still doesn't contain the Time
(my locale has a decimal comma)

Answer (score 1):

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) provided the crucial pointers in comments on the question (adding capture groups `(\d{2}:\d{2})` to the regular expression captures time strings such as `07:30`), and [LotPing's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41224827/45375) fleshed them out to a working solution that directly makes Nate's code work.

Let me offer a more concise alternative that uses PowerShell's type accelerators and casting:

```
Select-String $WLDir -pattern '(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(PMT[ST]\d{8})' -Context 0,2 |
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            Time = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
            Topic = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
            Status = $_.Context.PostContext[1]
            Elapsed = (
             [datetime] $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value - [datetime] $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
            ).TotalHours
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation $OutFile
```

- Casting the time strings captured via the first 2 capture groups (`$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` and `$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value`) to `[datetime]` converts them to `[datetime]` (`System.DateTime`) instances whose time portion reflects the specified time of day (and whose *date* portion defaults to today).
- You can directly subtract a `[datetime]` instance from another to get the time span between them: the result is a `[timespan]` (`System.TimeSpan`) instance, whose `.TotalHours` property can then be accessed.

Note that the solution assumes that PM values are represented in 24-hour format (e.g., 3 PM must be represented as `15:00`).

Comment: Thanks for simplifying my answer, I did try this and seem to have had a flaw in that, so I took the long road.

Comment: @LotPings. Thanks for the feedback. Overall, your solution ended up staying closer to Nate's own attempt, which is also helpful.